# Memory leak issue iOS NSCFString

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, xcode6

Original code using join() shows a memory leak in Instruments. I used a loop instead and it seems to have fixed the issue. Curious if this seems to be a framework issue?

```
 //in ViewDidLoad

      let saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Save, target: self, action: "saveBtnAc")
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton

    //end ViewDidLoad

   //using a loop to join the string instead of join()
   func doJndString(theArray: [String]) -> String {
        var updatedAryJnd = String()
        var count = 0
        let lastItemCount = theArray.count - 1
        while (count < lastItemCount) {
              updatedAryJnd += (theArray[count] + "§")
              count++
        }
        updatedAryJnd += theArray[lastItemCount]
        return updatedAryJnd
   }

   //button action

   func saveBtnAc() {
       var myAry = [""]
       if let items1 = setupItem?.valueForKey("itemsAry1") as? String {
       myAry = items1.componentsSeparatedByString("§")
       }

       myAry[itemClkdVar] = myTxtOutlet.text

       //I get a leak when using the following join()
       //let updatedAryJnd = "§".join(myAry)
       //setupItem!.setValue(updatedAryJnd, forKey: "itemsAry1")

       //change above to this and no leak
       setupItem!.setValue(doJndString(myAry), forKey: "itemsAry1")

       var error: NSError? = nil
           if !contextOb!.save(&error) {
                println("had an error")
           }        
    }
```

Comment: Can you please describe your error and your attempted troubleshooting in more detail? It's not super helpful to post a bunch of code and say "this is causing a memory leak". If you're getting a crash, please also post a symbolicated stack trace and any error messages that print in the console.

Comment: No crash, everything works fine. This is a slimmed down version of the total saveBtnAc code just for finding the leak, but it still causes it. The leak shows in Instruments as NSCFString. Instruments points to the updatedAryJnd section of code.

Comment: How are you detecting the leak?  If it's by using Instruments, that will show you exactly what is allocating the leaked object.  If not, use Instruments.  :)

Comment: And where you allocate may have nothing to do with where your error is. It just tells you what objects to audit the use of. There is no reason to believe the mistake is in the above code.

Comment: Code edited to reflect solution.